# Cant figure out how to correctly send this packet to server in PHP using socket_write

Tags: php, sockets

Ok,
So I know that I'm probably supposed to somehow convert this packet into some nicer form, but I honestly have no idea how, and cannot find any type of easy to understand explanation, basically I'm connecting using socket_connect, that's all fine and dandy.  I have used a packet sniffer to simulate the packet I'm trying to send, and basically just copied and pasted it.  This code basically freezes when it reaches socket_read, because the server isn't registering the data I'm sending it I assume, so it sends nothing back.  I think I'm supposed to use the PHP function "pack()" somewhere along the lines, but the documentation makes no sense to me and I'm just lost at this point.

Here's the code I have:

```
// this is the packet I want to send
$data =
'ff 50 3a 00 00 00 00 00  36 38 58 49 50 58 32 44 .P:..... 68XIPX2D
0c 00 00 00 53 55 6e 65  55 b4 4a c9 88 ff ff ff ....SUne U.J.....
09 04 00 00 09 04 00 00  55 53 41 00 55 6e 69 74 ........ USA.Unit
65 64 20 53 74 61 74 65  73 00                   ed State s.';

// i try writing it to the server, and it doesn't throw any error for me so seems to send it fine
socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

// then the server says nothing back, so it seems to just sit idle at this part
print(socket_read($socket, 2048));
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your packet sniffer give you the same data in 2 formats: Hexadecimal and String. The left part is hexa, the right one is String. For each hexa row, there is the corresponding String format in front. So, in your `data`, your packets are duplicated AND mixed up. You can't just copy/paste the output of your packet sniffer without knowing what those data are (i.e which elements of the hexa or string part you need).

Comment: In my example, there are 4 rows of data, does that mean I can just send it as:
`$data =
'ff503a00000000003638584950583244' .
'0c00000053556e6555b44ac988ffffff' .
'090400000904000055534100556e6974' .
'65642053746174657300';
$binary = hex2bin($data);
socket_write($socket, $binary, strlen($data));`
?

Comment: What I'm having trouble grasping is whether the server always expects binary or if the server is always expecting hex.  And in either case, I can't find any examples of multi-row hex being sent to a server in PHP that makes sense, it's always some short single row of hex, I need to send many rows at once it seems like.

Comment: i ended up figuring it out using the hex2bin, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you copy paste some hex editor content into `$data`. In fact you have a duplicate of your data. On the left of each line you have the data in hexadecimal, on the right you have the ASCII interpretation of these values.

So far, what you have in `$data` is a string that has absolutely no sense as a packet.

It seems you want to send byte by byte (ff then 50 then 3a ...), if it's the case you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473203/how-to-write-byte-by-byte-to-socket-in-php).

Comment: I don't think I'm trying to send byte by byte, it's supposed to be like this:
(DWORD) Protocol ID (0)
(DWORD) Platform ID 
(DWORD) Product ID 
(DWORD) Version Byte
(DWORD) Product language*
(DWORD) Local IP for NAT compatibility*
(DWORD) Time zone bias*
(DWORD) Locale ID*
(DWORD) Language ID*
(STRING) Country abreviation 
(STRING) Country